# How to update listview on ViewPager inside Activity or other viiewPager

Tags: java, android

I have one app that have 2 tabs:

- PESQUISA (Filter)
- SEUS FAVORITOS (Your Favorite).

The "PESQUISA" tab: this tab has some card views.

The "SEUS FAVORITOS" tab: this tab has a listview.

Whenever I click in one card into "PESQUISA" tab I would like that add the information about card into listview, but I don't know how to update the listview in "SEUS FAVORITOS" tab.
Actually, the listview is updated when I close and open app again.

I tried search some examples in stack-overflow, google, but I cannot find.

[image]

MY ACTIVITY

```
public class FiltersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CellPhone cellPhone;
    private FavoriteFragment favoriteFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filters);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
        titles.add(getString(R.string.search));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.your_favorite));

        cellPhone = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("currentCellPhone");

        final FiltersViewPagerAdapter mainViewPagerAdapter = new FiltersViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles, cellPhone);

    viewPager.setAdapter(mainViewPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

}

MY FAVORITE Fragment

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private CellPhoneFavoriteListAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<CellPhone> cellPhoneList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);

        mRecycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_result_phones);
        mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DatabaseSQLiteService dao = new DatabaseSQLiteService(view.getContext());
        cellPhoneList = dao.getAllFavoriteCellphone();

        mAdapter = new CellPhoneFavoriteListAdapter(view.getContext(), cellPhoneList);
        mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }
```

}

MY FragmentPagerAdapter

```
 public class FiltersViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private CellPhone cellPhone;

    public FiltersViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> titles, CellPhone cellPhone) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
        this.mFragmentTitleList = titles;
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;

        if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new FiltersFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("currentCellPhone", cellPhone);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        } else {
            fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("tipo", position);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

   @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>My sugestion is to replace the `List<String> titles`, which is local to `onCreate()`, by a member variable `List<TitleItem>` which could be accessed by any of the fragments using a callback on the `Activity`. (The callback can be done by casting `getActivity(`) to `FiltersActivity` in the Fragment, or by defining an `interface` and having `FiltersActivity` implement it.</s>

On another side, `TitleItem`, would have the title `String`, and the state which would indicate if it is a favourite or not.

When a title is selected from *PESQUIZA*, it would the change the item's state (in the list). When the user switches to *SEUS FAVORITOS*, the lisview would be repopulated with items with favourite state active.

To repopulate the listview, as a `ViewPager` is in use, it would have to be done when the fragment becomes visible vs. the loading ahead of time that `ViewPager` does. To do this override `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` and put the update logic in here.

**EDIT I**

I had wrongly interpreted the titles list as the list of items that could become favourites. After re-reading the question I see the items are being queried from the internal database.

What you cando is the following:

In the recycler view adapter add these methods:

```
public void setData(List<CellPhone> data) {
        this.data = data;
        refreshData();
}

private void refreshData(){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note: data is the dataset member variable you defined probably with a different name.

Then in the fragment:

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // Refresh your fragment here
        cellPhoneList = dao.getAllFavoriteCellphone();
        mAdapter.setData(cellPhoneList);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what I need do. It's possible give an example?

Comment: After re-reading the question I noted that I made a mistake. I thought titles had the list of items shown in the Pesquisa fragment which would become favourites if selected. Please can you add the Pesquisa code, what I wrote is applicable to what you are showing in the cards you mention.

Comment: Hi Juan, I had find one solution for my problem. I post the solution here and It's working. but, if possible, could you please check if this solution it's better solution? thank so much :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit(); I would call cellPhoneList = dao.getAllFavoriteCellphone(); and change the datasource for the recyclerview.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't know how to do this. :(

Comment: See the EDIT I in my answer.

Comment: Hey Juan, it's working now. thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to Juan help the correctly solution is:

In MY FAVORITE Fragment

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private CellPhoneFavoriteListAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<CellPhone> cellPhoneList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);

        mRecycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_result_phones);
        mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DatabaseSQLiteService dao = new DatabaseSQLiteService(view.getContext());
        cellPhoneList = dao.getAllFavoriteCellphone();

        mAdapter = new CellPhoneFavoriteListAdapter(view.getContext(), cellPhoneList);
        mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            // Update Listview  here
            DatabaseSQLiteService dao = new DatabaseSQLiteService(getContext());
            cellPhoneList = dao.getAllFavoriteCellphone();
            mAdapter.setData(cellPhoneList);
    }
}
```

}

and in MY ADAPTER I just add two method

```
public void setData(List<CellPhone> data) {
    this.itemsList = data;
    refreshData();
}

private void refreshData(){
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```